# Slug error while populating database- Django

Tags: python, django, scripting

I am new to django and currently learning the basics. However, I am stuck with the slug module.

Models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

After writing my models, I have run the migrations command and was successful.

Now as my database is empty, I have written a population script (containing dummy values) to populate my database.

But whenever I run the population script, I encounter an error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: exodus_category__new.slug
```

Population.py

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'kiran_blog_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

from exodus.models import Category, Page


def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat('Python',128,64)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Official Python Tutorial",
        url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/",views=20)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
        url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/", views=19)

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
        title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
        url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/",views=17)

    django_cat = add_cat("Django",64,32)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Official Django Tutorial",          url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/",views=30)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="Django Rocks",
        url="http://www.djangorocks.com/",views=21)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
        title="How to Tango with Django",
        url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/",views=50)

    frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks",32,16)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Bottle",
        url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/",views=13)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat,
        title="Flask",
        url="http://flask.pocoo.org",views=16)

    # Print out what we have added to the user.
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title)[0]
    p.url=url
    p.views=views
    p.save()
    return p

def add_cat(name,views,likes):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name)[0]
    c.views=views
    c.likes=likes
    c.save()
    return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting  population script..."
    populate()
```

However, I think the absence of a "slug " field in the population script is giving this error.

So what modifications do you suggest to be done in the population script so as to get rid of this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should set the `slug` field of a category.  If you don't do it then the empty value of this field will be not unique for the second category entry.

The simplest way to solve this issue is to use the [`slugify()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify) utility function:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify

def add_cat(name,views,likes):
    defaults={'views': views, 'likes': likes, 'slug': slugify(name)}
    return Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, defaults=defaults)[0]
```

**UPDATE**: To make string unicode add the `u'` prefix to the string literals:

```
python_cat = add_cat(u'Python', 128, 64)
```

Comment: I tried your solution and modified my population script according to it. When I ran the population script it showed an error  `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/text.py", line 442, in slugify
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
TypeError: must be unicode, not str`    [This is my models.py file](http://pastebin.com/u0rf9RbG)

Comment: Then use the unicode strings instead of bytestrings. See the update in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate you help @catavaran but again after updating I am stuck with this error when I run my population script. `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: exodus_category.slug
` also my updated population script is [here](http://pastebin.com/SR4MGxr9). Sorry for the small doubts as I am new to django.

Comment: The error says that there is no `slug` field in the database table.  Why the table names in your errors are differs?  If the first case it is `exodus_category__new` and now it is `exodus_category`.  Did you alter the `Meta` or something like this?

Comment: no @catavaran. I just deleted all the migration files and updated my models.py and then ran the migrations command. I did not change anything else [This is my file created in the migration folder](http://pastebin.com/APVwJ1Hb)

Comment: Are you sure that you use the same settings in your project and in the population script?  Migration file should create the table with the `slug` field so I suspect that your population script run against the wrong database.

Comment: I found the solution. I just tweaked the migration file after adding slug field to my model. [This is the updated migration file](http://pastebin.com/YBJWe676)   Thanks for your help!